# Ubuntu usb wont work on ASUS t100 transformerbook

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, asus, tablet

The ubuntu 16.04.1 usb i created will not work on the asus t100 transformerbook. No clue why. secureboot off, win8.1 tablet pc. All that happens is a black screen then windows boots.

Answer (score 1):

You need a customized version of the distro,  See the posts and files available on the [Asus T100 Ubuntu](https://plus.google.com/communities/117853703024346186936) Google+ group